# Is it possible to do dynamic routing based on domain URL with same paths with Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm hoping someone can help me and I hope I can explain this clearly enough:

Platform: Asp.Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages.

I have a situation where i would like to map the following

www.company1.com/home -> Pages/Company1/index.cshtml

www.company2.com/home -> Pages/Company2/index.cshtml

So if the domain url has company1 in it, it maps the url to the company1 folder structure and shows the homepage for that company. And if the domain url has company2 in it, it maps the url to the company2 folder structure.

So it would then also allow:

www.company1.com/Products/List -> Pages/Company1/Products/ProductList.cshtml

www.company2.com/Products/List -> Pages/Company2/Products/ProductList.cshtml

and so on... I don't want to have to prefix the company in the route e.g. I don't want to have to have www.company1.com/company1/products/list

Is this possible? It seems there would be duplicate paths but I would like to forward them to the correct endpoint file based on part of the domain url. I am trying to have one project which allows multiple customers to access their own webpages based on their domain url rather than having a website per customer.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you,

Ro

Comment: If you are going to place each customer's pages in a separate folder, it seems to me that you effectively have a site per customer. It looks like you have come up with a sub-optimal solution to a tenanted application to me.  How different will each customer's site be?

Comment: Thanks Mike and yes tenanted application is pretty much what I'm trying to achieve.
Each customers site will have their own look and feel i.e. styles and their own _layout page so they can look how they want them to and also some custom pages they might need, but then there will also be a common area all customers will have eg products hence I would like to have kept it in a single project. If I have to create a site per customer - if I want to add extra functionality to ALL customers it would mean republishing across all sites or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Maybe I need to do some reading on Multitenant ASP.NET Core Applications as a solution then.